# How to pull the auto generated unique ID after push in Firebase with Golang?

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firego to do operations on the firebase. I am unable to retrieve the auto generated unique ID after a successful push. I used the fllowing code:

```
adminData, err := dB.Child("Admins").Push(m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    log.Println("Unique ID: ", adminData)
```

and it print:

```
https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Admins/-KddtEfpE3ys4cj0mYE-/.json
```

the variable adminData is of type `*Firebase`

but I need only `-KddtEfpE3ys4cj0mYE-` as type `String`
How I can do this in Golang using firego?

Comment: BTW you don't have to use an auto generated key. You can use an email for example. That way, you will be able to access it directly later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firego does not expose this information, you can either create an issue to firego repository on github or modify the library yourself.

also there is a dirty way to split by `/` character and get last but one element.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    parts := strings.Split("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Admins/-KddtEfpE3ys4cj0mYE-/.json", "/")
    fmt.Println(parts[len(parts)-2]) // -KddtEfpE3ys4cj0mYE-
}
```

Though I would recommend you to open an issue to firego :)